# AngularJS $http keep adding a trailing slash to just one of my urls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iis, asp.net-web-api

I'm directly using angularjs `$http` service to interact with my API in just one of the cases HTTP service adds a trailing slash to my URL turning `http://localhost:4845/api/autocomplete?subject=committee` to `http://localhost:4845/api/autocomplete/?subject=committee` in other cases it works fine without modifying the given URL and I can't figure out the reason

This is the angularjs code, I'm not using any other modules/services/interceptors

```
$http.get('http://localhost:4845/api/autocomplete?subject=committee');
```

When I intercept the request on the server using an HTTP Module, I see that the `context_BeginRequest` method is called three times for the exact same request, first time without trailing slash two times with it.

There is no issue with other similar requests.

The api is ASP.NET WebApi 2 on IIS

Comment: Can we see your $http code please?

Comment: Please post your `$http` code. Without seeing that, it's tough to tell what the problem is. Are you using `$routeProvider` or `$locationProvider` at all?

Comment: There is no $http code I'm using $http service plain and simple no additional services

Answer (score 0):

After hours of investigation, I still don't know what is happening but I could resolve it, this issue is in fact not related to angular, angular calls the resource `/api/autocomplete` but what happens is that there **is a folder on the server with exact path as the resource I'm requesting** so the server somehow changes the request for a resource `/api/autocomplete` to a request for a folder `/api/autocomple/`.

If you debug angularjs you will see this as exactly after calling `xhr.send` in the network tab in the debugger tools we can see the correct call to `/api/autocomplete` in pending state, but after a while that changes to `/api/autocomplete/` with the result of 403 (forbidden)

Changing either the folder name or the resource name will resolve this issue

This behavior is observed in IIS Express